# Display block not working in css while designing hover slider

Tags: html, css

I am designing a hover slider which upon hovering should slide down a drop down menu which should be in block display, in style sheet after applying display: block; it still shows in inline only.

while trying to make it in block i applied directly display block to a element then everything printed in block as expected,but when trying to do with class **.slidercontent** its not working,that is its not displaying in block.

```css
.media {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .background {
      pointer-events:none;
      z-index: 1;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: rgba(43, 74, 111, 0.2);
    }

    .contents {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      z-index: 2;
      font-style: italic;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: rgb(27, 5, 58);
      border: solid 10px rgba(3, 35, 54, 0.6);
      padding: -3%;
    }

    .slidercontact {
      width: 80px;
      font-style: italic;
      font-size: 1.1em;
      color: rgb(7, 18, 58);
      background-color: rgba(122, 134, 173, 0.5);
      border: 3px solid rgb(6, 21, 57);
    }

    .slider {
      display: flex;
      margin-right: 1.9%;
      margin-top: -5%;
      margin-bottom: 1%;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: flex-end;
    }

   .slidercontent {
     display: none;
     background-color: rgba(196, 231, 154, 0.9);
     width: 187px;
    }
   .slider:hover .slidercontent{
     display: block;
    }

    .slider:hover .slidercontact {
      background-color: rgb(277, 0, 0);
    }
```

```html
<div class="media">
<video src="video.mov" autoplay loop
muted></video>`
</div>
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="contents">
 <h1>Registration Page</h1>
</div>
<div class="slider">
<button class="slidercontact">Contact</button>
<div class="slidercontent">
 <a href="#">1</a>
 <a href="#">2</a>
</div>
</div>
```

expected elements in block, but displaying inline.

Comment: Which elements are you expecting to be displayed as block? Your button and the hover menu are block (beneath one another). Your `<a>` tags are inline because they aren't set to `display: block;`. Your question isn't very clear, your `background` is covering your button (so you can't trigger the hover), you have a `z-index` on an un-positioned element, etc. You may be better off just posting a screenshot of what you want.

Comment: my slidercontents that are 1 and 2 are printed inline, i expect them to be in block,since in css i appliied , .slidecontents{display: block;}

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with `.background`. It is absolutely positioned and on top of everything else on the page in its own stacking context. Because of this, the hover on `.slider` was not triggering. I removed the class and moved the `background-color` to `body`.

### Update

To make the links with text `1` and `2` on their own line, you have to set `block` on the `a` inside of `.slidercontent`.

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: rgba(43, 74, 111, 0.2);
}

.media {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.contents {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 2;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(27, 5, 58);
  border: solid 10px rgba(3, 35, 54, 0.6);
  padding: -3%;
}

.slidercontact {
  width: 80px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: rgb(7, 18, 58);
  background-color: rgba(122, 134, 173, 0.5);
  border: 3px solid rgb(6, 21, 57);
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 1.9%;
  margin-top: -5%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.slidercontent {
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(196, 231, 154, 0.9);
  width: 187px;
}

.slidercontent a {
  display: block;
}

.slider:hover .slidercontent {
  display: block;
}

.slider:hover .slidercontact {
  background-color: rgb(277, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="media">
  <video src="video.mov" autoplay loop muted></video>`
</div>
<div class="contents">
  <h1>Registration Page</h1>
</div>
<div class="slider">
  <button class="slidercontact">EmailID</button>
  <div class="slidercontent">
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">2</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ,still my elements 1,2 are inline not block display.

Comment: Your solution is correct, but just wanted to point out that there is a `;` missing in the OP's question in `.background`. That's actually causing the behaviour you've mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

you want to display the content inside the `.slidercontent` as a block.

first of all the `.background` is absolutely positioned which comes on top of the UI and prevent the code to trigger `.slider:hover`

secondly content inside the `.slidercontent` is `<a>` tag which is inline elements.

so need to change your code as :

```
.background {
 /* add a line in the background class*/
    z-index: -1;
}

/* to make the <a> tag block */
    .slidercontent a {
      display: block;
    }
```